# Python loop that writes files from requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

am trying to write a loop that gets .json from an url via requests, then writes the .json to a .csv file. Then I need it to it over and over again until my list of names (.txt file) is finished(89 lines). I can't get it to go over the list, it just get the error:

```py
AttributeError: module 'response' has no attribute 'append'
```

I can´t find the issue, if I change 'response' to 'responses' I get also an error

```py
with open('listan-{}.csv'.format(pricelists), 'w') as outf:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "listan-['A..
```

I can't seem to find a loop fitting for my purpose. Since I am a total beginner of python I hope I can get some help here and learn more.

My code so far.

```py
#Opens the file with pricelists

pricelists = []

with open('prislistor.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        pricelists.append(line.strip())

# build responses 
responses = [] 
for pricelist in pricelists: 
    response.append(requests.get('https://api.example.com/3/prices/sublist/{}/'.format(pricelist), headers=headers))

#Format each response 
fullData = [] 
for response in responses: 
    parsed = json.loads(response.text)
    listan=(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

    #Converts and creates a .csv file.
    fullData.append(parsed['Prices'])



with open('listan-{}.csv'.format(pricelists), 'w') as outf:
    dw.writeheader()
    for data in fullData: 
        dw = csv.DictWriter(outf, data[0].keys())

        for row in data:
            dw.writerow(row)

print ("The file list-{}.csv is created!".format(pricelists))
```

Comment: Show value of `pricelists`

Comment: Add an s for ``responses/append``, and check why ``pricelist`` is a list of list

Comment: The pricelist is a list of list, because I need the loop to trough every single line on the line on the line list use one line of the list at a time and then get the data from request and write it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the below changes in the place where you are making the api call(import json library as well) and see?

```
import json
responses = [] 
for pricelist in pricelists: 
    response = requests.get('https://api.example.com/3/prices/sublist/{}/'.format(pricelist), headers=headers)
    response_json = json.loads(response.text)
    responses.append(response_json)
```

and the below code also should be in a loop which loops through items in pricelists

```
for pricelist in pricelists:
    with open('listan-{}.csv'.format(pricelists), 'w') as outf:
        dw.writeheader()
        for data in fullData: 
            dw = csv.DictWriter(outf, data[0].keys())

            for row in data:
                dw.writerow(row)

    print ("The file list-{}.csv is created!".format(pricelists))
```

Comment: I got another error. ```python parsed = json.loads(response.text)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'text' ```

Comment: Can you give me one example value that you would be passing in {} of "https://api.example.com/3/prices/sublist/{}/" . i.e any one of pricelist value.

Comment: Yes, so the pricelist value is a textlist with different names basically. Like, "CARL"

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. Got a help from another questions I created here at the forum. @waynelpu

The misstake I did was to not put the code into a loop.

Here is the code that worked like a charm.

```
pricelists = []

with open('prislistor.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f): # from here on, a looping code block start with 8 spaces
        pricelists = (line.strip())
        # Keeps the indents
        response = requests.get('https://api.example.se/3/prices/sublist/{}/'.format(pricelists), headers=headers)

        #Formats it
        parsed = json.loads(response.text)

        listan=(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

        #Converts and creates a .csv file.
        data = parsed['Prices']

        with open('listan-{}.csv'.format(pricelists), 'w') as outf:
            dw = csv.DictWriter(outf, data[0].keys())
            dw.writeheader()

            for row in data:
                dw.writerow(row)

        print ("The file list-{}.csv is created!".format(pricelists))

    # codes here is outside the loop but still INSIDE the 'with' block, so you can still access f here

# codes here leaves all blocks
```